# How to remove trailing zeros from a string?

Tags: java, string

I have a string `salePrice` which can have values like `29.90000,91.01000` and i want to get the output like `29.90,91.01` as in with the two digits after decimal points. i am using a string.

Comment: those are trailing zeros, not leading zeros

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: @Raedwald Not a dup; this question wants to keep the last two digits

Comment: read this before you continue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency , and http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 15):

One of possible solutions

```
new BigDecimal("29.90000").setScale(2).toString()
```

Or if you need to round

```
new BigDecimal("29.90100").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString()
```

**Using BigDecimal because converting from String to double can lose precision!**

Choose rounding mode that fits your case.

Comment: +1. `BigDecimal` is often overlooked.

Comment: Oh, by the way, that's "lose" :p But a `double` indeed has loose precision :p

Comment: @fge, **Good answer** must be **correct and funny**!

Comment: BTW it will fail for 29.90100

Answer (score 8):

Try this...

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,###.##" );
double dd = 100.2397;
double dd2dec = new Double(df2.format(dd)).doubleValue();
```

Comment: +1, but shouldn't it be `#,###,###,###.##`? Because the number doesn't always end with `0.00`

Comment: @Doorknob Jeje... Fixed...

Comment: as a matter of fact it should be "0.00" instead to have fixed 2 digits after decimal point

Answer (score 6):

```
int lastIndex = salePrice.indexOf(".") + 2
salePrice = salePrice.substring(0, lastIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
String.format("%.2f", value);
```

Comment: @yannishristofakis   Thanks for sharing.value is a common term when representing some value.And convering value to string is not a big deal.So lets wait for OP response,weather he is able to get it or not.Good day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Commons Mathematics Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/)

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    ComplexFormat cf = new ComplexFormat(nf);
    Complex complex = cf.parse("29.90000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old-school way that matches your question (you always want 2 decimal places)

```
public class LearnTrim
{
    public static void main(final String[] arguments)
    {
        String value1 = "908.0100";
        String value2 = "876.1";
        String value3 = "101";
        String value4 = "75.75";
        String value5 = "31.";

        System.out.println(value1 + " => " + trimmy(value1));
        System.out.println(value2 + " => " + trimmy(value2));
        System.out.println(value3 + " => " + trimmy(value3));
        System.out.println(value4 + " => " + trimmy(value4));
        System.out.println(value5 + " => " + trimmy(value5));
    }

    private static String trimmy(final String value)
    {
        int decimalIndex;
        String returnValue;
        int valueLength = value.length(); // use StringUtils.length() for null safety.

        decimalIndex = value.indexOf('.');
        if (decimalIndex != -1)
        {
            if (decimalIndex < (valueLength - 3))
            {
                returnValue = value.substring(0, valueLength - 2);
            }
            else if (decimalIndex == (valueLength - 3))
            {
                returnValue = value;
            }
            else if (decimalIndex == (valueLength - 2))
            {
                returnValue = value + "0";
            }
            else // decimalIndex == valueLength - 1
            {
                returnValue = value + "00";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = value + ".00";
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```