# How to remove a trailing zero from a string

Tags: java

How to remove trailing zero in java for a `String`

below is my string values,
908.10001
508.1000
405.000
302.0000
15.880

I want the output like
908.10001
508.1
405.0
302.0
15.88

Comment: Read [Remove trailing zero in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984664/remove-trailing-zero-in-java)

Comment: or read this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984462/how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-from-a-string

Comment: you can use decimal format too !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple solution:

```
String string1 = Double.valueOf("302.1000").toString();  // 302.1
String string2 = Double.valueOf("302.0000").toString();  // 302.0
String string3 = Double.valueOf("302.0010").toString();  // 302.001
```

Comment: @Marjer: If you don't want to convert to and back from double then you could try `System.out.println(val.replaceAll("(\\..+?)(0*)$", "$1"));`.

Answer (score 0):

I think String replaceAll method can take a regex in parameter, so it can do what you want. i might look something like this:

```
String s = s.indexOf(".") < 0 ? s : s.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

Comment: That doesn't give the desired result though, e.g. 302.0000 should become 302.0

Comment: It's not workin as excepted, prints 100 for 100.000

Comment: Oh yes indeed... I did not noticed that requirement. Then you can used Braj solution.

Comment: Not working as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to address trailing non-zeros too. Try BigDecimal with a scale of 1 and ROUND_HALF_UP rounding (if that works for you):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("302.0000");
System.out.println(bd.setScale(1,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString()); //outputs 302.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and use [stripTrailingZeros()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29).

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("302.00000").stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(bd.toString());
```